# Convert MIME to RichText

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino, xpages-ssjs

I would like to convert a domino document field of `Data Type: MIME Part` into a `Data Type: Rich Text` in **backend** with `SSJS` or `Java`?

---

I have tried to work with

```
doc.computeWithForm(true, true);
doc.save(true, true);
```

but this piece of code has no effect.

---

Hint: I can do this conversion with a notes client in **frontend** (open and save the document) without any problems.

Any idea? Thanks in advance!

Comment: OT: why would anyone want to convert MIME to Richtext?  I think that way  would cause more trouble than having it in MIME - except your app has to display it "comfortably" in the client.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/nd85forum.nsf/dba3ca7e515d55ff85256a0700727b35/eb29f6744ca3bbee85257a090000f159?OpenDocument

Comment: @OliverBusse: I have to deal with a 3rd party pdf renderer which works better with `RichText` instead of `MIME`.

Comment: @KnutHerrmann: I have rewritten the code (http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/nd85forum.nsf/dba3ca7e515d55ff85256a0700727b35/eb29f6744ca3bbee85257a090000f159?OpenDocument) in SSJS but It doesn't work for me :(

Comment: Too bad. You might add your SSJS code to your question so we can test it too.

Comment: @KnutHerrmann: I think this piece of code only works on the **frontend** notes client.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may be able to do this as part of the usually-undesirable side effect of automatic MIME-to-CD conversion in the API. For example, code like this will turn the Body field of the first doc in the DB from MIME to composite data:

```
boolean convertMime = session.isConvertMime();
session.setConvertMime(true);
Document doc = database.getAllDocuments().getFirstDocument();
RichTextItem rtitem = (RichTextItem)doc.getFirstItem("Body");
rtitem.compact();

doc.save();
session.setConvertMime(convertMime);
```

By making sure that the session is converting MIME (which is `true` by default, but it's best to maintain any previously-existing value) and then interacting with the MIME_PART item, it will mangle it into CD for you.

Comment: For others hitting the same issue I had I just want to add that by setting the convertMime option we managed to get attached files from MIME fields using the embeddedObjects from a standard RT field :-)

Comment: @Jesse Gallagher I've been trying this, but I keep getting a class cast exception when I get the body field: " ClassCastException: org.openntf.domino.impl.Item incompatible with org.openntf.domino.RichTextItem".  could this be because of updates in the last year?

Comment: It shouldn't be - that sounds more like the item you're dealing with isn't actually a rich-text item. I'd suggest checking the document in question, or adding a test like `Item foo = doc.getFirstItem("Body"); if(foo.getType() == Item.COMPOSITE) { ... }` (I forget if it uses "COMPOSITE" there, but you get the idea).